# Return records based on the result of a function

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have records as follows:

1) BEL
  1) MERSEN
  A) VISHAY-SPRAGUE
  CIRCUIT PARTNERS
  BENTEK
  CIRCUIT TEST

I want to return a distinct set where if the record has a closing bracket, then remove the entire bracket prefix ( 1) MERSEN becomes MERSEN) otherwise return the record as is. This is an ad hoc, one off query.  I've tried something like this.

```
IF (CHARINDEX(')', (SELECT [MANUFACTURER] FROM [dbo].[QPL_ITMSUPAC_NF]), 1) > 0)

    SELECT DISTINCT SUBSTRING([dbo].[QPL_ITMSUPAC_NF].[MANUFACTURER], 4, 99)
    FROM [dbo].[QPL_ITMSUPAC_NF]

ELSE

    SELECT DISTINCT [dbo].[QPL_ITMSUPAC_NF].[MANUFACTURER]
    FROM [dbo].[QPL_ITMSUPAC_NF]
```

...but get the error:

> Subquery returned more than 1 value...

The above was in a procedure.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `exists` and move the function into the subquery.  In this case, the `charindex()` is equivalent to `like ')%'`:

```
IF (EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM [dbo].[QPL_ITMSUPAC_NF] WHERE MANUFACTURER LIKE ')%') )
    SELECT DISTINCT SUBSTRING([dbo].[QPL_ITMSUPAC_NF].[MANUFACTURER], 4, 99)
    FROM [dbo].[QPL_ITMSUPAC_NF]
ELSE
    SELECT DISTINCT [dbo].[QPL_ITMSUPAC_NF].[MANUFACTURER]
    FROM [dbo].[QPL_ITMSUPAC_NF]
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do it with using `right` function, with taking help from `len` and `charindex` functions:

```
select right(MANUFACTURER,len(MANUFACTURER)-charindex(')',MANUFACTURER)) 
from QPL_ITMSUPAC_NF
```

*Example:*

```
select right('1)a sample name',len('1)a sample name')-charindex(')','1)a sample name'))
```

*Output:*

```
a sample name
```

Comment: Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '1) ANALOG DEVICES' to data type int.

Comment: I am really sorry for the typo, try again

Answer (score 0):

your subquery `SELECT [MANUFACTURER] FROM [dbo].[QPL_ITMSUPAC_NF]` is returning more than 1 value (a table) but the charindex() function is expecting only 1 value.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT LTRIM(RIGHT(MANUFACTURER,LEN(MANUFACTURER) - CHARINDEX(')',MANUFACTURER)))
FROM QPL_ITMSUPAC_NF
```

...returned 2552 records

```
IF (EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM [dbo].[QPL_ITMSUPAC_NF] WHERE MANUFACTURER LIKE ')%') )
SELECT DISTINCT LTRIM(SUBSTRING([dbo].[QPL_ITMSUPAC_NF].[MANUFACTURER], CHARINDEX(')', [MANUFACTURER], 1) + 1, 99))
FROM [dbo].[QPL_ITMSUPAC_NF]
ELSE
SELECT DISTINCT [dbo].[QPL_ITMSUPAC_NF].[MANUFACTURER]
FROM [dbo].[QPL_ITMSUPAC_NF]
```

...returned 2495 records.

Close enough for my needs, thanks.